# how to Split a string with in double quotes in java

Tags: java, string

I have a doubt in splitting a string, my requirement is i have to split the string with 'and' or 'or' separated, and if the 2 or 3 words come with in double quotes, i have to keep this as a single String. please look at the following example, here i have given string like this "India or welcome and \"This is America.\"";

the output should come like below:

1. first string --> India
2. second string --> Welcome
3. third string ---> This is America.

this is only for examples, i have to split a string like this from huge paragraph..

for ref:

```
public class Test 
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
       try{
           String s2="India or welcome and \"This is America.\"";
           System.out.println(s2);
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.err.println("Exception Ocurred:"+e);
       }
    } 
}
```

Please give me the suggestions for this requirement, and also suggest me the efficient way to split the string. which one is best stringtokenizer or String.split().

another thing is my string may like this also String s2= "one two three four \"five six seven\""
i have to split this as like below,

1. one
2. two
3. three
4. four
5. five six seven

i want like this also.. plese provide me the suggestion

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your example does not make sense to me. "This is America" wouldn't be split anyway because it neither contains "and", nor "or". The double quotes don't affect this at all.

Comment: I agree.  The requirements are contradictory.  The Question is not answerable in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String s2 = "India or welcome and \"This is America.\"";
        String[] split = s2.split("and|or");
        System.out.println(s2);
        for (String string : split) {
            System.out.println(string.trim());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception Ocurred:" + e);
    }
}
```

I am wandering what you need if there is 'and' or 'or' in the quotes. example:

```
String s2 = "India or welcome and \"This and America.\"";
```